# Need help in python dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, search

This code saves a number of key and value pair from the user but I want to go further and enter keys to be searched in phone book .Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code

```
phonebook = {}
n = int(input())
for x in range (n):
    name , phoneno = input().split()
    phonebook[ name ] = int(phoneno)
for y in phonebook:
    name = input().split()
    if name in phonebook:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print('Not Found')
```

Comment: so it seems like you dont need `for y in phonebook:`

Comment: Can *you* tell us whats wrong with the code? What does it do that you dont expect?

Comment: `name = input().split()` creates a list, use `name = input()` to stick with a string.

Comment: "Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code" Well, did you **try running it**? What happened? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? Now, look at the structure of your code. Can you think of something that explains why that happened? Going through the code a piece at a time, can you explain, in plain English words, the exact intended purpose of each part?

Comment: Please read [ask], and also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

```
phonebook = {}
n = int(input())
for x in range (n):
    name , phoneno = input().split()
    phonebook[ name ] = int(phoneno)

name = input().split()
out = phonebook.get(name,None)
if out == None:
    print('Not found')
else:
    print('found')
```

You don't need a loop to check for a key in a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

In `name , phoneno = input().split()` the `.split()` needs an argument on what to split it on, so lets say you did thisGuy 69420, if you did `.split(' ')` space being the argument `name & phoneno` would both be a list, which at `index [0]` would be `thisGuy` and at `index[1]` would be `69420`

Hopefully, that helps :)